# Create table error

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`a` int NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `d` int DEFAULT 0,
  `e` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `f` varchar DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`,`c`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I run this query, I get the following error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL,   `emailId` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
>   `score` int DEFAULT 0, `stat'

I have tried insert after removing columns. I get the same error.

I am not able to find out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pls paste the actual create table statement, not a sanitised version!

Comment: The code you've shared has at least one blatant syntax error. The same seems to happen with the undisclosed code that triggers that error message.

Comment: put varchar length

Comment: Closed reasons doesn't suit. Is it the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length is missing in varchar, set the varchar length as per below-

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `a` int NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `d` int DEFAULT 0,
  `e` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `f` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`,`c`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the length of the varchar for field `b` and `f`:

```
 `b` varchar DEFAULT NULL,
```

Declare the length of the field, like

```
 `b` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Comment: You forgot about `f`

Answer (score 0):

You missed length of Varchar ,try to give length of varchar,

Here is query

```
  CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `a` int NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `d` int DEFAULT 0,
  `e` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
   `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `f` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`,`c`,`timestamp`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```